# LLVM: Make LLVMFP128Type from long double

Tags: c, floating-point, llvm, llvm-ir, 128-bit

In LLVM, there is a `LLVMFP128Type`, though I cannot seem to find out how to convert an actual `long double` into a `LLVMValueRef` of type `LLVMFP128Type` directly.

I can do the following (with a `double`):

```c
LLVMValueRef var = LLVMBuildAlloca(
    builder,
    LLVMDoubleTypeInContext(ctx),
    "x"
);

double num = 3.1415;

LLVMBuildStore(
    builder,
    LLVMConstReal(
        LLVMDoubleTypeInContext(ctx),
        num
    ),
    var
);
```

Generating the following LLVM IR:

```
%x = alloca double
store double 3.141500e+00, double* %x
```

But how to I do the same for a `long double`? There is a `LLVMConstRealOfString` function, which takes makes a constant float from a string, though I find it inefficient to have to convert to and from a string using something like `sprintf`:

```c
LLVMValueRef var = LLVMBuildAlloca(
    builder,
    LLVMFP128TypeInContext(ctx),
    "x"
);

// long double num = 3.1415L;

LLVMBuildStore(
    builder,
    LLVMConstRealOfString(
        LLVMFP128TypeInContext(ctx),
        "3.1415" // would have to sprintf `num`
    ),
    var
);
```

Gives the following (desired) LLVM IR:

```
%x = alloca fp128
store fp128 0xLE978D4FDF3B645A24000921CAC083126, fp128* %x
```

How can I get the desired results (lower example) with the simplicity of the first example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about those `LLVMBuildStore` but GCC, ICC and Clang there's already a [`__float128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html) as an extension so you can just use it. `__float128 x = 3.1415;` results in the following LLVM IR

```
%7 = load fp128*, fp128** %4, align 8, !dbg !22
store fp128 0xLF0000000000000004000921CAC083126, fp128* %7, align 16, !dbg !23
```

[Demo on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:6,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:6),source:%27void+f(__float128+*x,+long+double+*y,+double+z)%0A%7B%0A++++*x+%3D+3.1415%3B%0A++++*y+%3D+z%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-emit-llvm%27,selection:(endColumn:39,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:39,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:3),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

In fact `long double` is mapped to `__float128` for most modern architectures. In x86 there's hardware support for extended precision so it's mapped to `__float80` and you can use the [`-mlong-double-128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html) option to make it an [IEEE-754 binary128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) type, i.e. `__float128`. On PowerPC `long double` uses [double-double arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Double-double_arithmetic) by default and you can use [`-mabi=ieeelongdouble`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/RS_002f6000-and-PowerPC-Options.html#index-mabi_003dieeelongdouble) to get the same effect as above

Comment: The question is about generating the appropriate ir for the store operation.